# Moving video slices in timline in Sony Vegas

Tags: vegas-pro

I am completely beginner in montage.. I started with sony vegas pro 13... my problem is : when I drag a slice of a video in timeline it return to its place automatically
I mean that I can't change its place in timeline
I tried to search google a lot but nothing.
Sory if it was silly question

Comment: Check if the video clip is locked (right-click on clip and go down to the Switches sub-menu and see if Lock is ticked). If not, check the same for any other clips with which it is grouped (like its associated audio or any other clip). You can check if it is grouped by looking in the Group sub-menu in the same dropdown.